# antlr 3.5.1 generates code for C runtime with undeclared indentifier: _empty. any fix available?

Tags: antlr3

It seems that antlr-3.5.1-complete.jar and antlr-3.5.1-complete-no-st3.jar generates 
code targeting C runtime that has a lot of the "_empty" identifier in the DFA that 
is not defined anywhere.

antlr-3.4 generates the code using dfa31_T_empty which should be the correct id.

I could probably fix this by defining _empty as NULL but that's a hack.

Is there any antlr-3.5.2 or so available that fixes this error?

Cheers,
Adrian Pop/

Comment: This belongs on the project issue tracker at https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have encountered this error too. The simplest and cleanest solution indeed seems to be to add this to your grammar:

```
@header
{
   #define _empty NULL
}
```

The other solution is to add this define to your compiler macro list (`/D _empty=null` seems to work in both GCC and MSVC).